# Moving application to the cloud, Tomcat, Java, MySQL - Azure/AWS options LAMP or services?

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, azure, tomcat

I need to bring over a system from locally hosted to cloud services.  Right now the system runs on Tomcat 6, MySQL 5.1 and JDK 8.xx running on Windows Server 2012

What is the best approach to move this forward - right now it is running on Windows Server, for licensing costs, etc it seems cheaper to move to Linux as the OS and spin up a LAMP server or use AWS or Azure services for a serverless solution if I understand things correctly.  I understand there are also solutions like Bitnami with pre-built environments.

This is far from my area of expertise so I'm looking for advice on the current preferred solutions for this kind of setup.  Not married to Azure, AWS, any particular solution.  Wondering what needs to happen code wise too so we can take the necessary steps to move to new infrastructure.

Any advice, pitfalls, solutions would be welcome just to find some direction.  Sorry if this seems vague can offer up more info as needed.

Comment: At least for AWS your biggest issue is that Tomcat 6 hasn't been supported for about 3 years or so.  MySQL 5.1 ended support 7 or so years ago.  So first things first - you're either going to have to have a dedicated type server (i.e. an EC2 in AWS) or you need to do some upgrades.  Once that happens I'd look at the [Tomcat support in Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html) as a possible solution on the AWS side.

Comment: Why are you looking at LAMP servers if your application is Java/Tomcat? LAMP stack is for PHP applications.

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm sure we will need to push up our versions to current as part of the migration and wonder what that will break as we try and adapt to a new environment.  I'm thinking it would be better to go through that pain vs trying to spin up a server to support the older versions only to have to upgrade them anyways over time.

I can't seem to nail down the type of person or service that could advise/consult on such matters.  I will check out the Elastic Beanstalk for starters for Tomcat - thank you!

Comment: I don't need the P I guess - see my lack of experience showing.....

Comment: @Chris you don't need the A or the P. Apache Web Server is not the same thing as Apache Tomcat. I second the recommendation for Elastic Beanstalk, along with an RDS MySQL server.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, checking into Elastic Beanstalk. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good solution is to move towards containerized solution. Both [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/) and [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) offer managed Kubernetes service. Moving to container based solution will also have added benefit in your case that you can build your own container even with older versions of your existing apps or pick base image from the plethora of public images (e.g. for Tomcat https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat). So it will be quicker migration with lift and shift approach.

For more details about container service offering in Azure, refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/containers/

Comment: Interesting, I'll check in to Kubernetes too!  Thank you.